# Blocking a trusted certificate in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate, heartbleed

Is it possible to somehow block a certain certificate that is currently trusted by my browser?

The reason is the recently discovered [Heartbleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed)-attack which I also found out to affect my netbanking (awesome), so until they fix it and issue a new certificate I would like to add them to a not-trusted list. Or maybe I should just get [Verisign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisign) to revoke their certificate?

Comment: Revocation is the only secure solution and obviously roll out the fix itself

Comment: rolling out the fix is kinda hard for me as a customer, but I'll report the cert for revocation then ;)

Comment: Heartbleed is a TLS problem not a certificate problem. Revoking the cert will not fix the issue, because TLS heartbeats can be invoked at any time, including during TLS handshake.

Comment: but if i get a huge-ass certificate warning i might think twice about actually using the site (and also its a nice trigger to know once they have fixed the issue and got a new cert)

Comment: It is a certificate problem because this exploit can compromise the certificate unless perfect forward is enabled of course